# Horizontal axis labelling causes white space on y axis

Tags: graph, customization, stata

This is my data:

```
input y1 y2 y3 x
-0.34834709 -0.02733159 -0.6137266 97
-0.3906476 -0.12309019 -0.68878702 98
-0.43213382 -0.23861568 -0.76169004 99
-0.47270931 -0.28437565 -0.76154058 100
-0.51234194 -0.36507922 -0.81745737 101
-0.55110669 -0.44603292 -0.78759176 102
-0.58892858 -0.56973828 -0.89383692 103
end
```

A plot using a standard theme, looks alright:

```
tw connect y1 y2 y3 x, legend(off) ytitle("This is the title of the y axis") scheme(s2mono)
```

However, if I use my custom scheme, I get a large space between y-axis and y-axis title:

```
tw connect y1 y2 y3 x, legend(off) ytitle("This is the title of the y axis") scheme(custom)
```

[image]

I have been using this scheme for years and I had never problems of this kind.

This line from my `.scheme` file causes the white space (commenting out removes it):

```
anglestyle vertical_tick horizontal
```

This seems weird, as the tick labels are pretty short, i.e. the space created is not really needed.

How could I tweak the scheme to force the axis title to be closer to the axis while maintaining the horizontal labelling?

By the way, I'm unable to reproduce this behavior with some `sysuse` data, that's why I provided the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with the specified scheme (custom or not). This is an output `format` problem. Using your toy example:

```
clear
input y1 y2 y3 x
-0.34834709 -0.02733159 -0.6137266 97
-0.3906476 -0.12309019 -0.68878702 98
-0.43213382 -0.23861568 -0.76169004 99
-0.47270931 -0.28437565 -0.76154058 100
-0.51234194 -0.36507922 -0.81745737 101
-0.55110669 -0.44603292 -0.78759176 102
-0.58892858 -0.56973828 -0.89383692 103
end

tw connect y1 y2 y3 x, legend(off) ytitle("This is the title of the y axis") ///
ylabel(, angle(horizontal))
```

[image]

If you specify the desired output format, the problem goes away:

```
tw connect y1 y2 y3 x, legend(off) ytitle("This is the title of the y axis") ///
ylabel(,angle(horizontal) format(%3.1f))
```

[image]